# Real time reactive form with Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, meteor, handlebars.js

I've started learning Meteor and there are a few initial concepts that I'm still not grasping.

In Ember/Handlebars I can write something like this

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{input type="text" value=name}}
  Hello, {{name}}
</script>
```

And whenever the user types something in the input box, it would display in real time.

How to achieve the same in Meteor? I've tried this

```
<div>
  <input type="text" value="{{name}}">
  Hello, {{name}}
</div>
```

But it is not working. Do I need to explicitly write a Meteor event for that to happen?

Comment: The short answer is yes, you need at least a template event handler.  `value="{{name}}"` in the input element does not set up bidirectional data flow.  `{{name}}` there is merely evaluated on the (re) generation of the template containing the input element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on Paul’s answer, yes, you need to define an event. Also the template needs to know where to get the value for `name` from. Here’s a more fleshed-out example:

```
<template name="hello">
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="{{name}}">
    Hello, {{name}}
  </div>
</template>
```

and:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Session.setDefault("name", "world");

  Template.hello.helpers({
    name: function () {
      return Session.get("name");
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'keyup input': function (event) {
      Session.set("name", event.target.value);
    }
  });
}
```

Live example: http://meteorpad.com/pad/TsHu27WASi6KdqaA6

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late one but to complete Geoffrey's answer:

It's actually [recommended](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables) to use scoped 
[ReactiveVar](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html) 
or [ReactiveDict](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict)
when dealing with non global variables like form data.

Assuming this template:

```
<template name="form">
  <form>
    <input id="firstName" type="text" value="">
    <input id="lastName" type="text" value="">
    <p>Hello, {{fullName}}</p>
  </form>
</template>
```

As you can notice, I'm not setting input value directly in the template to avoid infinite loops with `onChange` event.

With `ReactiveVar`:
first run `meteor add reactive-var` in your terminal at project root, then:

```
import { Template }     from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar }  from 'meteor/reactive-var';

Template.form.onCreated(function() {
  this.form = new ReactiveVar({
    firstName : '',
    lastName  : ''
  });
});

Template.form.helpers({
  fullName : () => {
    let form = Template.instance().form.get();
    return `${form.firstName} ${form.lastName.toUpperCase()}`;
  }
});

Template.form.events({
  'keyup #firstName, change #firstName'( event ) {
    let form = Template.instance().form;
    form.set(Object.assign(form.get(), { firstName : event.currentTarget.value }));
  },
  'keyup #lastName, change #lastName'( event ) {
    let form = Template.instance().form;
    form.set(Object.assign(form.get(), { lastName : event.currentTarget.value }));
  }
});
```

With `ReactiveDict`:
first run `meteor add reactive-dict` in your terminal at project root, then:

```
import { Template }     from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveDict } from 'meteor/reactive-dict';

Template.form.onCreated(function() {
  this.form = new ReactiveDict();

  this.form.set('firstName','');
  this.form.set('lastName','');
});

Template.form.helpers({
  fullName : () => {
    let form = Template.instance().form;
    return `${form.get('firstName')} ${form.get('lastName').toUpperCase()}`;
  }
});

Template.form.events({
  'keyup #firstName, change #firstName'( event ) {
    Template.instance().form.set('firstName', event.currentTarget.value);
  },
  'keyup #lastName, change #lastName'( event ) {
    Template.instance().form.set('lastName', event.currentTarget.value);
  }
});
```